# How can I $match on everything in an if...else?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I'm setting up a MongoDB aggregation pipeline and part of it is using a $match if a parameter is provided, or else trying to $match everything.

There's a method, self.products(), which returns a list of every product I'd like to query if no parameter is provided but I can't figure out how ti either integrate that or use $match with a wildcard for everything.

```
    self.pipeline = [
        {
            '$lookup':
                {
                    'from': 'timeseries',
                    'localField': '_id',
                    'foreignField': '_id',
                    'as': 'everything'
                }
        },
        {
            '$unwind': '$everything'
        },
        {
            '$project': {
                '_id': 1,
                'header': 1,
                'item': 1,
                'data': '$everything.data'
            }
        },
        {
            '$match': {
                'product.real': product if product else self.products()
            }
        }

    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with:

```
{
    '$match': {
        'product.real': product if product else {'$exists': True}
    }
}
```